# Can you move a background with CSS without moving text?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm currently working on a website where the logo does not work in Internet Explorer: http://core2062.com/

The creator of this site made the text a hyperlink and then applied background-image to add the logo behind it. In browsers besides IE, the logo shows up to the left of the text. This is the CSS I am using: http://dev1.core2062.com/wp-content/themes/CORE-Website/style/ie.css

The actual HTML for the logo is:

```
<a id="logo" href="http://core2062.com" title="Click here to go back to the main page.">CORE<br/>2062</a>
```

Since the text and background are both in a hyperlink, I have no way of modifying either just the text or just the background without modifying the other. Since there is no way to target just the text in the hyperlink, is it possible to somehow move the background manually to the left, or otherwise move the text to the right?

I tried setting margin-left and padding-left to 0 but that moved both the background and text to the left, which is why I'm looking to move one but not the other.

I have not modified any of the HTML (the br is not mine). It was coded about 10 years ago.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: `background-position` _does_ move the background while not moving the text. So what exactly _is_ the problem? According to _Can I Use_ [`background-position` is supported by IE 11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-position-x-y).

Comment: It works for me

Comment: I am testing live at http://dev1.core2062.com/ and no matter what I do for background-position nothing happens

Comment: You tried `background-position:100px 100px;` ? Or somesuch?

Comment: When I do that, the logo just disappears, leaving the text behind

Comment: So it gets moved somewhere right? Did you try with only 10px?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It reappears, but is to the right - even worse than in the beginning.

Comment: I can manipulate the logo itself, but not in a way that gets the logo the left of the text in a way that it's not on top of it. I've tried a number of combinations...

Comment: Oh. Wait. I forgot you are testing in IE. Give me a minute.

Comment: This is going to take me a few to get Windows running in a VM.

Comment: No problem, thanks for helping

Comment: Which version of IE. I have IE11 on Win7 and it's the same as the other browsers.

Comment: I am testing on IE11 on Win7. The way I am targeting the browser though will only apply to IE10 and IE11.

Comment: Do you know you can use negative numbers like -30px?

Comment: Woah... that seems to do it. background-position: -45px 5px seems almost right on. I'll keep tweaking it until it looks like it supposed to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I put this as an answer will you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `background-position` with a negative number, such as -45px as tried in the comments, the logo can be pushed off the side from its normal positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the pattern here is to use `text-indent: -9999px` on a logo `<a>` to hide the text (while leaving it for the semantic meaning--for search engines, for example).

[`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) will move the text `-9999px` to the left (outside of the bounds of the `<a>`), but the background will remain as is.

To position the background beyond this, use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).